# javascript scrollTop not working in div

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, scroll

I have two divs on my page. The first one (optionSelect) is not scrollable and stays at the very top of the page. The other one (dataView) is scrollable and is right under the first one.

I'm trying to retain the second div's scrollbar position on postbacks using scrollTop, but it's not working. I verified that the scrollTop() value is being set by displaying it in a TextBox.

On a page update, I change the text in that TextBox to the value of div2's scrollTop(). (working)

On page load, I want to set div2's scrollTop() to the previous value. (not working)

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

CSS:

```
.optionSelect {
    font-family: Consolas;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 245px;
}

.dataView {
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 245px;
bottom: 0;
}

body {
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
   var currentScroll = "<%=GetScrollPosition()%>"; // C# function to get scroll position value
   $("div.dataStyle").scrollTop(currentScroll);

   function beforePagePostback() {

        $("#loadingImage").show();

        var position = $("div.dataStyle").scrollTop();

        $("#ScrollPositionTextBox").prop("value", position); // sets scroll position to text box

        "<%=SetScrollPosition()%>"; // C# func that gets the scroll position from the text box
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about this construction: `$("#ScrollPositionTextBox").prop("value", position);` - have you tried this instead: `$("#ScrollPositionTextBox").val(position);` ?

Comment: The TextBox value is being set fine as I can see the value changing when I refresh my page, but I can try that. The scrollbar position is not changing though. scrollTop(currentScroll) still keeps it at the top no matter what.

Comment: Is your javascript in a document ready function? Or is that the complete javascript?  If it's the complete javascript, then the issue is that the script is running before the page is loaded, and you're not able to manipulate the elements because it's not fully loaded first.  `jQuery(function($) { ... your code to run after page load here ... });`

Comment: It's not currently, but even when I put the code into that `jQuery(function($) {    $("div.dataStyle").scrollTop(currentScroll);
});`, it still works the same.

Comment: At this point, without seeing the markup, and the full context of the code, it's hard to say.  Do you use firebug and watch for javascript errors? If you do `$("div.dataStyle").css("border", "2px solid red");` does that work?  It's hard to know if it's the selector, the js, etc.

Comment: That works, so I guess the selector is fine. Also the selector doesn't get highlighted until the rest of the UI is loaded (not sure if that tells you anything). Thanks for the help, btw! I'm really lost as to what might be going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order my C# functions were being called was wrong.

I had to SetScrollPosition() before GetScrollPosition(). I thought that SetScrollPosition() would be called before the page load since beforePagePostback() is called before the page is updated.. but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but your javascript says div.dataStyle and your css class is dataView. Are these supposed to be one and the same or is there something else we're not seeing?

Without C# but scrolltop is working: http://jsfiddle.net/ecarlsonweb/ys3LA/

```
var currentScroll = "40"; 

$(function(){
    $("div.dataView").scrollTop(currentScroll);
});
```

Comment: oh that was my bad when copying my code over. They actually match.

Comment: Do you think calling a C# function messes things up?